# SQL - Greatest-n-per-group of the average

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, average, greatest-n-per-group

I am having trouble with the following query. Lets say you have the following table of employees:

Example table `EMPLOYEE`:

```
IDEMP |    JOB    | SALARY | CONTENT 
------+-----------+--------+---------
  1   |   CLERK   |  1500  |   ...   
  2   |   CLERK   |  1000  |   ...   
  3   | PRESIDENT |  5000  |   ...   
  4   |  ANALYST  |  2000  |   ...   
  ...       ...       ...      ...
```

I am trying to obtain the JOB that has the highest average salary. I can easily obtain the average salary of each JOB with this subquery:

```
(select job, avg(salary) as AVERAGE 
 from emp
 group by job) temp
```

However, I don't know how I can obtain after this subquery the max(AVERAGE) with the associated JOB. I know that if I only needed the row of the employee with the highest salary, I could do it as explained here [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column), but when you do the 'average subquery' you lose the IDs of the employees.

Since for this given example there is only one PRESIDENT, and the job has the highest average salary, the output should be this:

```
   JOB    |  MAX_AVERAGE 
----------+---------------
PRESIDENT |     5000
```

**EDIT: My solution...**

Thanks for the help, you brought up new ideas. I'm finally using this one because it does not limit the results to one row.

```
select e.job, avg(e.salary) as AVERAGE 
 from EMPLOYEE e
 group by e.job
 having avg(e.salary) >= ALL(select avg(salary) from EMPLOYEE group by job)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: What if two jobs have the same maximum average salary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out one query that returns my desired result and is also more flexible than the previously ones posted since it can return multiple rows if it was the case:

```
select e.job, avg(e.salary) as AVERAGE 
 from EMPLOYEE e
 group by e.job
 having avg(e.salary) >= ALL(select avg(salary) from EMPLOYEE group by job)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort your query by descending average and pick the top row:

```
select job, avg(salary) as AVERAGE 
 from EMPLOYEE
 group by job
 order by AVERAGE desc limit 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f66c00ffe49465a23de2909bd792d0d3).

Comment: that's actually very simple and smart, I guess I don't have that much of experience to have thought about that!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below - **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=753f8fbb7b9fa1e9348fa23aadc1424a)**

```
with cte as
(
select job,avg(salary) avg_sal
from t1 group by job
)
select * from
(
select job,avg_sal, row_number() over(order by avg_sal desc) as rn
from cte
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: And I thought I knew SQL, damn